# What gives diarrhoea caused by Cholera its milky colour?

Tags: infection, bacterial-toxins

The diarrhoea caused by the Cholera bacteria is a milky colour, also known as 'rice-water' like. Why is this? I have a fairly good understanding of how Cholera acts on the body.

Answer (score 1):

The color of our feces is caused by the breakdown products of the hemoglobin, namely [Bilirubin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilirubin) and [Stercobilin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stercobilin), which depending on the concentration, cause a yellow to brown color. See [here](http://www.medicinenet.com/stool_color_changes/article.htm) for details.

Since the amount of liquid lost by the [cholera diarrhea](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/962643-clinical) with up to 250ml/kg bodyweight is really high, there is only very little to nothing of these breakdown products available in the feces. This causes an absence of color.